# Are database commits strictly ordered on read?

Tags: sql, database, transactions, commit, acid

While facing some challenging concurrency issues, I have surprised myself by realising that I didn't know the answer to this question and would value any feedback.

Imagine a transaction we shall call **Bob**, executing the following:

```
UPDATE Foo SET value='A' WHERE value='B'
COMMIT;
```

And a second transaction we shall call **Alice**, running parallel with Bob, doing the following:

```
UPDATE Bar SET value='X' WHERE value='Y'
COMMIT;
```

We cannot predict in which order Alice and Bob complete.

Now imagine two more transactions, **Carol** and **Dan**, running with a `READ COMMITTED` (or higher) isolation level.  They are running in parallel with Alice and Bob such that they may or may not "see" the effect of either Alice or Bob. They *both* do the following:

```
SELECT Foo.value, Bar.value FROM Foo, Bar;
```

**Is it possible** that the following might occur in a single run:

- Carol reads `Foo.value = 'A'` and `Bar.value = 'Y'` (Alice commited, Bob not committed)
- Dan reads `Foo.value = 'B'` and `Bar.value = 'X'` (Bob committed, Alice not committed)

That is, is it possible that they both only see the effect of one transaction, but see *different ones* - or to put it another way, they perceive the transactions having occurred in a different order?

Both are logically serializable outcomes, and arguably both atomic, consistent 
and isolated views.

Might this behaviour differ between `SERIALIZABLE` and `READ COMMITTED`? What about different platforms (e.g. Oracle, PostGres, SQL Server, MySQL and H2 in particular).

Comment: It's not possible *both* that Alice commits before Bob, *and* that Bob commits before Alice. Is that how this question really boils down?

Comment: The answer may be that simple, yes. I strongly suspect that Oracle at least maintains a monolithic commit sequence, but I’m not 100% certain, and I can’t find anything explicit about the others.